# QGIS problem with exporting from print composer

Tags: qgis, printing, print-composer, qgis-2.10

I am using QGIS (version 2.10.1-Pisa) on a Mac (Yosemite). I am trying to export a map in the print composer as jpg or pdf and whenever I do try, the page in the print composer goes blank. when trying to save as jpg, a file is saved but the image is black. it also saves a pdf but the file is empty.
I am basically trying to print some simple vector layers on top of a google hybrid background.

Comment: do you have transparency in your project?

Comment: Are you using the open layers plugin? That doesn't work with print composer...